# is_digit функция возвращает False, а должно быть True

Tags: python, функции, функциональное-программирование

```
def is_digit(digit):
    digit = str(digit)
    digits = '0123456789'
    if '.' in digit:
        if len(digit.split(".")) > 2:
            return False
        for value in digit.split("."):
            is_digit(value)
    for value in digit:
        if value in digits:
            continue
        else:
            return False
    return True


print(bool(is_digit("1.322")))
```

Comment: В цикле `for value in digit:` очевидно попадается точка, из-за которой возвращается `False`

Comment: А цикл `for value in digit.split("."): is_digit(value)` абсолютно бесполезен, потому что вы никак не используете значение, которое возвращает вызываемая здесь функция `is_digit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужно только проверить, но не конвертировать то можно сделать так:

Исправленная функция (спасибо @andreymal за замечания в комментариях!):

```
def is_float(num):
    try:
        _ = float(num)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Первоначальный (**неправильный**) ответ - ломался на строках типа `"."` или `"1e5"`:

```
def is_float(num):
    s = str(num)
    return s.count('.') <= 1 and set(s).issubset(set('.0123456789'))
```

Тесты:

```
In [160]: is_float("123")
Out[160]: True

In [161]: is_float("1.23")
Out[161]: True

In [162]: is_float(".123")
Out[162]: True

In [163]: is_float("1.2.3")
Out[163]: False
```

Если же целью является конвертация в вещественное число, то я бы сделал так:

```
def to_float(s):
    try:
        return float(s)
    except ValueError:
        return None
```

Тесты:

```
In [169]: print(to_float("123"))
123.0

In [170]: print(to_float(".123"))
0.123

In [171]: print(to_float("1.23"))
1.23

In [172]: print(to_float("1.2.3"))
None
```

Comment: С числами вида `1e5` получается что-то неоднозначное, хз допустимы ли они для автора

Comment: Кстати, `is_float('') => True` и `is_float('.') => True` :)

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо, сейчас постараюсь исправить

Comment: `is_float("0.0") => False` :)

Comment: @andreymal, да, уже сам заметил, спасибо! ;-)